# Rkhunter reports openssl warning

Tags: centos, openssl, rkhunter

I have installed and configured rkhunter on Centos and I have no warning except

Checking version of OpenSSL                              [ Warning ]

when I check log file I see that I need to update openssl

```
root@server [~]#  openssl version -a
OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
built on: Mon Jun 15 18:29:40 UTC 2015
platform: linux-x86_64
options:  bn(64,64) md2(int) rc4(16x,int) des(idx,cisc,16,int) idea(int) blowfish(idx)
compiler: gcc -fPIC -DOPENSSL_PIC -DZLIB -DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -DKRB5_MIT -m64 -DL_ENDIAN -DTERMIO -Wall -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -Wa,--noexecstack -DPURIFY -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAES_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DBSAES_ASM -DWHIRLPOOL_ASM -DGHASH_ASM
OPENSSLDIR: "/etc/pki/tls"
engines:  dynamic
```

I have tried to update openssl with yum openssl update but, it says it is up to date

```
root@server [~]# rpm -q --changelog openssl | grep CVE-2014-0224
- fix CVE-2014-0224 fix that broke EAP-FAST session resumption support
- fix CVE-2014-0224 - SSL/TLS MITM vulnerability
```

Please tell me what to do to fix this warning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RedHat/CentOS doesn't take complete new versions of packages like OpenSSL into older releases, they "backport" only security fixes; see https://access.redhat.com/security/updates/backporting .

Note the "build" date in `version -a` is much newer than the OpenSSL release date for 1.0.1e. And if you look at the version in the *rpm name* with `rpm -q` you should see `openssl-1.0.1e-30.el6` -- the "-30" indicates the backports added to what started as upstream 1.0.1e.

If you just need a *secure* version, you've got it. If you want the *current* possibly incompatible version, you can build from upstream source; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22952287/how-to-upgrade-openssl-in-centos-6-5-linux-unix-from-source . Basically it's like most opensource projects: `tar zx && ./config [opts] && make && make test && make install`; see the `INSTALL` file and/or the `Configure` script (at top dir of the extract) for details.

Comment: Would not recommend tarballing. You risk breaking the system. Roll an rpm instead.

Answer (score 1):

I had this in the past too on RedHat with version 1.0.0. Had the latest version according to RedHat. You can either ignore this message or add `APP_WHITELIST="openssl:1.0.0"` so that `rkhunter` accepts this version and does not print the warning.

Comment: I know about that and it is solution for ignoring warning, but why is it reporting as obsolete. Why I cant update it?

Comment: I think that RedHat/Centos are not so keen on installing the latest version. I have several servers running the RedHat 6 and I have the same version as you but my rkhunter is not complaining (it is still allowing version 1.0.0 :-)). Perhaps your rkhunter is to old. If it is really insecure then they would quickly put the latest version in their repository (or at least I hope so).